# Missing warning about format specifier in variadic template context

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, compiler-warnings

The following code produces warning about wrong format specifier in all major compilers

```
std::wstring ws = L"some example string";
char buff[100];
sprintf(buff, "%s", ws.c_str());
```

The warning disappears if we use it in 'variadic' context (variadic template or va_list).

```
std::wstring ws = L"some example string";

void foo_va_list(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list argv;
    va_start( argv, fmt );

    char buff[1000];
    vsprintf(buff, fmt,  argv);

    va_end(argv);
}

template<typename ... T>
void foo_variadic_template(const char* fmt, T && ...  args)
{
    char buff[100];
    sprintf(buff, fmt,  args...);
}


int main()
{
    //this two should produce a warning but don't
    foo_va_list("foo_va_list %s", ws.c_str()); 
    foo_variadic_template("foo_variadic_template %s", ws.c_str()); 

    char buff[100];
    //this one produces warning as expected 
    sprintf(buff, "sprintf %s", ws.c_str());
}
```

The question is how to enable this warning in this context?

Comment: Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/Y-KEmr

Comment: Warnings are compile-time things. If a compiler sees something that is wrong, it may issue a warning. Pointers are run-time things. They can point to anything and the pointed-to-thing might change anytime. The compiler is not able to track down what a pointer could point to, so it does not issue a warning in that case.

Comment: Ok, I see now, the issue is rather in making is a function call, not in template itself.

Answer (score 0):

some compilers have an extension for the `[s]printf` functions and can "understand" the given format string and check the used format specifier against the used arguments.

Obviously these checks can not work if you hide this relation in your own implementation.